# I want to make a div appear when you click a button

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with creating a div that when you click a button, the div with custom HTML inside gets created.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var template = `
   <div class="block">
      Hello World!
      </div>
`
function createBlock() {

}
   </script>
   <button onclick="createBlock()">Create div</button>
</html>
```

If this is possible(it most likely is), I am making a post box thing.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
var template = `
   <div class="block">
      Hello World!
      </div>
`
function createBlock() {
  let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.append(myDiv);
    myDiv.outerHTML = template;
}
```

```css
.block{ background: red }
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <button onclick="createBlock()">Create div</button>
</html>
```

If you want put your template as a child inside new div you can change your `createBlock` like this:

```
function createBlock() {
  let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
  myDiv.innerHTML= template;
  document.body.append(myDiv);
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to create an element, but if you keep clicking the button, you can constantly keep duplicating and appending the element, which you might not want.

Comment: Right, in the question there isn'n anything about prevent duplication, in ordrer to prevent duplicate `<div.block>` you can check it before create new one, like this: 
`const blockElement = document.querySelector('.block');
 if(blockElement == null){ //create new div.block element } `. Thanks for the important point.

Comment: thanks you Saeed!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an element, a better way to do this (with the same effect) is hiding and then showing the element, like so:

```css
#block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<button onclick="createBlock()">Create div</button>
  <div id="block">
    Hello World!
   </div>
      
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function createBlock() {
    block = document.getElementById("block")
    block.style.display = "block"
  }
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```